# How do I use Android's CountDownTimer?

Tags: android, counter

How do I use the Android's CountDownTimer?

I basically want to have the following scenario:

```
boolean 3_s_passed = false;
// setup counter to change 3_s_passed=true when it finishes
counter.start();
while(true){

if(3_s_passed || user_is_Done) break;
// do some stuff which may set user_is_Done to true

}
```

So either 3 seconds passed or the user finishes and I'm out of the loop.
Will the while-loop code run before the counter finishes? Is my understanding of the CountDownTimer correct?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a handler for this.  Make a `Runnable` with the task to complete after 3 seconds or when the user does the task.  Post it for 3 seconds and remove callbacks if the user does whatever.  The code same below shows how to properly use the `Handler` but isn't looping to allow the user to make the action you'll have to figure that out on your own :)

```
Runnable action = new Runnable(){

    public void run(){
       //...
    }
};

mHandler.postDelayed(action, 3000);
if(userDone){
  mHandler.removeCallbacks(action);
  mHandler.post(action);
}
```

Comment: Hmm. If I understand this correctly, the mHandler, adds action to the message queue at 3 s. However, if userDone, mHandler cancels that action request, and tells Android to add the action to the message queue now. Is that correct? Also wondering if userDone=true, would action be guaranteed to run before the code after the if-statement? The idea of a queue always worries me with timing errors and race conditions.

Comment: you are correct about your understanding of handler, but your second question isn't very clear.  If you call mHandler.post(action) it will definitely execute the runnable it that is what you are asking...

Comment: Thanks for your reply. To clarify the second part: say i had code after the if-statement, and mHandler.post(action) was executed. Would action be guaranteed to execute BEFORE my code?

Comment: ahh yes, the handler posts to whatever thread it is created in so if you create the handler in the same thread that the if statement is running in it will execute all of the code in `action` before moving to the next line.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use this class it contains a race in cancel method.
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=58668

cancel don't work in case of race between onTick and cancel.

It's better to implement it from scratch without races.
In other case you will have a problem until official fix.